# "every statement and declaration an expression that yields a value" why?

Tags: language-design

At the end of the answer to "Can I do ++x and x++ in Python?" on this page: http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html, you can read:

> [...] I'm with my fellow Dane, Bjarne Stroustrup, on this one. He said in The Design and Evolution of C++ ``If I were to design a language from scratch, I would follow the Algol68 path and make every statement and declaration an expression that yields a value''.

Why?

Comment: You mean why Bjarne would do that if he designed a language from scratch? You'll have to ask him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any design, removing exceptional scenarios makes for a cleaner design - those branches interact with the rest of the design causing cascading impacts. By allowing all expressions (and statements) return a value (even if that value is `unit`) allows the design to be simpler. Further, it allows you to get functionality for "free" without having to make specialized versions for statements versus expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The main aims and principles of design of ALGOL 68:

1. Completeness and clarity of description
2. [Orthogonal design](http://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/report.html#012),
3. Security,
4. Efficiency:

   - Static mode checking
   - Mode-independent parsing
   - Independent compilation
   - Loop optimization
   - Representations - in minimal & larger character sets

> 0.1.2 [Orthogonal design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science)
>
> The number of independent primitive concepts has been minimized in
>   order that the language be easy to describe, to learn, and to
>   implement. On the other hand, these concepts have been applied
>   "orthogonally" in order to maximize the expressive power of the
>   language while trying to avoid deleterious superfluities.

“[ALGOL 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68) was the first (and possibly one of the last) major language for which a full formal definition was made before it was implemented.” — [C.H.A. Koster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornelis_H._A._Koster)